# Genesis theme development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I am trying to make a custom genesis theme form HTML file.I tried several times in google to find some resource.But i failed.So basically is there any good resource is available to make custom them from scratch..

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion:

1. Read "How to Build a Genesis Child Theme" tutorial from Bill Erickson. (also mentioned by Carele)
   http://www.artofblog.com/building-a-genesis-child-theme/
2. Use the free themes from Brian Gardner to learn
   http://briangardner.com/themes/
3. Use copyblogger's sample Genesis theme on github as a base when you start creating your own child theme. 
   https://github.com/copyblogger/genesis-sample

Answer (score 0):

After a quick research, this seems pretty clear and full.

http://www.artofblog.com/building-a-genesis-child-theme/

Indeed you can't just take a html file and "convert" it into wordpress theme. You gotta make a child theme from it. You have to break it up and insert your code within the php (keeping the structure as close as possible as your parent theme.

Here are some interesting tips I usually follow as well.

http://briangardner.com/building-custom-genesis-theme/

Comment: thanks carele for the reply.But can you suggest me some screencast or any in depth resources for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to develop a theme using genesis framework, than it is not very straightforward from the first sight. You will need to use their hooks and filters and modify/swap the output of each section of their pre-defined theme skeleton. Here is a link with more details:
http://designsbynickthegeek.com/tutorials/genesis-explained-the-framework

If you want another resource, I would recommend using http://underscores.me/ starter theme.

Comment: Underscore is for traditional theme development.I have decent knowledge on traditional theme development.But i want to get used to with genesis theming now.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for learning Genesis theme development will be the treehouse course by Jesse Peterson or Carrie Dils' Genesis courses on Lynda.com https://www.lynda.com/Carrie-Dils/965233-1.html both offer free trials which should help get you started!